# Update mapping of elastic index using ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, mapping

I am using elastic index named Equipment_Dashboard, I am using following code to add bulk data in the index.

```
var bulkDescriptor = new BulkDescriptor();

foreach (var elasticModel in elasticEquipmentListModel.ElasticEquipmentList)
{
    // Document does not exist, so insert it
    bulkDescriptor.Index<ElasticEquipmentModel>(i => i
        .Document(elasticModel)
        .Id(elasticModel.EquipmentId)
    );
}

// Publishing document
var response = _elasticClient.BulkAsync(bulkDescriptor);
```

In my index, I have an `isDamaged` property:

```
     "isDamaged": {
        "properties": {
            "value": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "yesNoValue": {
                "fielddata": true,
                "analyzer": "keyword_lowercase",
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "query": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, in my dashboard, `isDamagedFlag` field is used which is not there in my index, it is getting mapped using json file.

```
"isDamaged": {
                    "properties": {
                        "value": {
                            "copy_to": [
                                "isDamagedFlag"
                            ],
                            "fielddata": true,
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "sort": {
                                    "type": "text"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "yesNoValue": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "isDamagedFlag": {
                    "fielddata": true,
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "sort": {
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    }
                }
```

On C# side, this code is used to map all the properties to index.

```
AcknowledgedResponseBase putMappingResponse = _elasticClient.LowLevel.Indices.PutMapping<PutMappingResponse>(newIndexName, MappingsRootPath);

if (putMappingResponse.Acknowledged)
{
    // return true;
}
```

I want to update new properties in Index for mapping, for example `isDamaged.value` to map with `isDamagedFlag` using copy_to. How can I achieve this with ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue?